# Gefore FX 5200 Ultra & 3D in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, nvidia-geforce, 3d-graphics, photoshop-cs5, 3d

I am running a Nvidia Geforce FX 5200 Ultra video card in my computer. I am attempting to work with some 3D in Photoshop CS5.1 extended. When I work with the 3D I get this message:

```
Your video card does not meet the requirements for hardware-accelerate 
3D rendering. All 3D will be rendered with software only.
```

According to the [technical specs](http://www.nvidia.com/page/pg_20040109440047.html) it supports 3D rendering or am I reading something wrong?

I have updated the drivers to the newest version [according to nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp_175.19_whql.html). Am I missing something or is there anyway to get this video card to work in Photoshop to use hardware accelerated 3D rendering?

***UPDATE*** I attempted the hack that the answer below provided. It does not work yet I came across a couple of great pages for information - [GPU, OpenGL support | Photoshop CS4, CS5](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404898.html)  and [Optimize performance | Photoshop CS4, CS5](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/404/kb404439.html)

Comment: CS5 is from 2010.  This video card initially came out in **2003**.  I'm just guessing, but I'd assume it simply doesn't support the features Photoshop needs for hardware accelerated rendering (and even if it did it would be slow as hell).

Comment: @Shinrai - I realize that, I am running an old computer and have to use what I have to work with. If I can get it to even add a little bit of performance boost will help because it already is slow as hell =>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FX5200 is not on the [list of supported Video Cards](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/831/cpsid_83117.html) for hardware-enabled 3D rendering in Photoshop.

It looks as though you'll need a minimum 7000 series NVidia card.

Though making sure you have the latest drivers with your current card should always be your first step in diagnosis.

That said, [there's suggestions for workarounds](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2462645) in the Adobe forums, including enabling support of older cards. However, comments in the Adobe Forums indicate the benefit you'd get from trying to make the older card run the hardware acceleration would be minimal.

Comment: I know users who have used unsupported video cards and it still worked. And I will look into the workarounds any benefit would be helpful. =>

Comment: I would have answered, had I been able to find this page! +1.  IMO if you can afford a copy of CS5 you can afford to upgrade your hardware.

Comment: @Shinrai: Heh, yea. I'd love to be able to afford CS5.

Comment: @Shinrai - It was given as a gift to me (A wonderful gift I must say) and hardware upgrades are in the future...just no money now!

Comment: @Lynda - I completely sympathize. We make do with what we've got.

Comment: That is true =>   Thanks for your assistance, I am going to see if that workaround will work but not sure if it will. Thanks!

Comment: @Lynda - That is quite a generous gift.  I hope you can manage to get it functional until you can put a little more horsepower behind it. :)

Comment: @Shinrai - yes it is, and it works mostly but the 3D is VERY slow, but most of everything else works great but can get slow at times =>